# Update the value in nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the Basic Recipe array with the details objects:

I want to be able to update the value of specific item inside the details i.e item with ID 5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b

```
{
  "brandName": "Piatto",
  "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e29",
  "name": "Test",
  "rate": 89,
  "baseQuantity": 1000,
  "baseUnit": "gm",
  "details": [
    {
      "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b",
      "rawMaterial": "Egg white 1",
      "brandName": "Bisleri",
      "supplier": "Dasnya",
      "type": "Solid",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 12,
      "quantityInRecipe": 0,
      "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      "recipeUnit": "ml",
      "displayRateUnit": "1/2 lit."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2a",
      "rawMaterial": "Egg white 2",
      "brandName": "Bisleri",
      "supplier": "Dasnya",
      "type": "Solid",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 14,
      "quantityInRecipe": 0,
      "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      "recipeUnit": "gm",
      "displayRateUnit": "1/2 lit."
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yourData.details.forEach((item)=> if(item.id === yourId){ //update item });

Comment: Instead of `map` use `forEach`. Map use for returning array. Here no need of returning array. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var data = {
  "brandName": "Piatto",
  "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e29",
  "name": "Test",
  "rate": 89,
  "baseQuantity": 1000,
  "baseUnit": "gm",
  "details": [{
      "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b",
      "rawMaterial": "Egg white 1",
      "brandName": "Bisleri",
      "supplier": "Dasnya",
      "type": "Solid",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 12,
      "quantityInRecipe": 0,
      "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      "recipeUnit": "ml",
      "displayRateUnit": "1/2 lit."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2a",
      "rawMaterial": "Egg white 2",
      "brandName": "Bisleri",
      "supplier": "Dasnya",
      "type": "Solid",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 14,
      "quantityInRecipe": 0,
      "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      "recipeUnit": "gm",
      "displayRateUnit": "1/2 lit."
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
};
var idToBeUpdate = '5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b'
data.details.forEach(x => {
  if (x._id === idToBeUpdate) {
    x.rawMaterial = "Egg white 3 <updated>"
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could use a `filter` function to get element you want to update based on `_id`, and then modify it like:

```js
let input = {
  "brandName": "Piatto",
  "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e29",
  "name": "Test",
  "rate": 89,
  "baseQuantity": 1000,
  "baseUnit": "gm",
  "details": [
    {
      "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b",
      "rawMaterial": "Egg white 1",
      "brandName": "Bisleri",
      "supplier": "Dasnya",
      "type": "Solid",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 12,
      "quantityInRecipe": 0,
      "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      "recipeUnit": "ml",
      "displayRateUnit": "1/2 lit."
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2a",
      "rawMaterial": "Egg white 2",
      "brandName": "Bisleri",
      "supplier": "Dasnya",
      "type": "Solid",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 14,
      "quantityInRecipe": 0,
      "costOfRawMaterial": 0,
      "recipeUnit": "gm",
      "displayRateUnit": "1/2 lit."
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}


let elementToUpdate = input.details.filter(el => el._id === "5f3aadd5d756e9341ef74e2b")[0]
// this is the element filtered by _id
console.log(elementToUpdate)
//lets say you want to update rawMaterial
elementToUpdate.rawMaterial += ", Egg black 2"
console.log(elementToUpdate)
// this is the input object modified
console.log(input)
```

Comment: Instead of `filter` you can use `find`.